# IBM MQIPT SSL Handshake issue

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

We are connecting java MQ client to customer IBM MQ server, To connect that we have one MQIPT instance at cloud premises , and one MQIPT instance at non cloud premises . Once disabled SSL security on non cloud premises then we are able to connect that. However , once SSL enabled by non cloud premises we are facing SSL handshake issue.  Certificates are shared between us.

We don't have access on that non cloud environment.

[image: We are following the below design to connect mq]

We are connecting MQIPT by Java client . and below are the trace which we are getting in mqipt trace.

1. When we are not setting cipher at mq java client then we are getting below error

In that case MQIPT enabled for all cipher.

```
Issuer: 'CN=********* TEST CA ****,OU=*****,O=******** AG,C=******'
12:45:13.799    27   1414-2s         Processing keyType: RSA
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         No RSA certificates in keyring
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         Processing keyType: DSA
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         No DSA certificates in keyring
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         Processing keyType: EC
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         No EC certificates in keyring
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         WARNING: No suitable certificate to send to the remote server
12:45:13.800    27   1414-2s         --------} IPTX509KeyManager.chooseClientAlias() rc=0
12:45:14.184    27   1414-2s         SSLHandshakeException handshaking:com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:7)
```

2. But when we set CipherSuite in java MQ client then we are getting error logs in mqipt

```
MQCPI014 Protocol eyecatcher (16030300) not recognized
```

MQIPT Version --> IBM MQ Internet Pass-Thru V9.2.0.1

MQIPT conf as below

```
[global]
CommandPort=1884
RemoteShutDown=true
MinConnectionThreads=5
MaxConnectionThreads=100
IdleTimeout=20
ClientAccess=true
QMgrAccess=true
HTTP=true
HTTPChunking=false
Trace=5
ConnectionLog=true
MaxLogFileSize=50

[route]
Name=Route_1
Active=true
ListenerPort=1414
Destination=mq-dmz-************
DestinationPort=********
HTTP=true
HTTPS=true
SSLClient=true
SSLClientProtocols=TLSv1.2
SSLClientKeyRing="path of key ring PFX file"
SSLClientKeyRingPW="path of password file"
HTTPServer=<Http Server name>
HTTPServerPort=443
URIName=<URI name>
SSLClientCAKeyRing="same as SSLClientKeyRing"
SSLClientCAKeyRingPW="same as SSLClientKeyRingPW"
SSLClientCipherSuites=SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Comment: MQIPT Version --> IBM MQ Internet Pass-Thru V9.2.0.1                                                                                                   [global]
CommandPort=1884
RemoteShutDown=true
MinConnectionThreads=5
MaxConnectionThreads=100
IdleTimeout=20
ClientAccess=true
QMgrAccess=true
HTTP=true
HTTPChunking=false
Trace=5
ConnectionLog=true
MaxLogFileSize=50

Comment: @JoshMc : sorry for that , My intention is not to rollback your changes, accidently it done by me

Comment: Done and removed that tag  @JoshMc

Comment: yes we are using http

Comment: we are not using proxy on our side as we are client. but on the server side I don't have any idea .

Comment: we need to use without SSLProxyMode, we want our mqipt to decrypt and re-encrypt . thanks @JoshMc for giving your valuable time to this problem

Comment: On our side we are acting as client . does SSLServer property is also required to us

Comment: Keyring/certificates are ok, we tested without cipher suite and found that, is working fine. but when I used cipher suite in java ibm mq client program that is start giving error  "MQCPI014 Protocol eyecatcher (16030300) not recognized"  .

Comment: When I tried with SLServer=true, I am getting "unrecognized ssl message, plaintext connection" error in mqitp logs

Comment: I am working on that I will update it soon .  Thanks for your input .

Comment: @JoshMc:  Thank you so much for your input , we just make both mqipt  SSLServer=true, and SSLClient=true with the same cipher suite. and that start working . Yes , CAkeyring and keyring defined for both client and server.

Comment: I wrote up an answer with the details I had previously provided in my comments.  Please take a look and accept and vote it up if you found the info I provided useful.  Thank you.  I have cleaned up my comments as all the information I provided is in my answer.

Comment: Just a small question after everything working fine, we are getting sockeTimeout at mqipt after multiple successful connection. we are getting MQRC_Connection broken issue. This is not very frequent , but after multiple sending or receiving messages we are getting this. @JoshMc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup for accepting the connection from the MQ client, decrypting, and then re-encrypting and sending on to the next hop should look something like the following:

```
[route]
Name=Route_1
Active=true
ListenerPort=1414
Destination=mq-dmz-************
DestinationPort=********
HTTP=true
HTTPS=true
SSLClient=true
SSLClientProtocols=TLSv1.2
SSLClientKeyRing="path of key ring PFX file"
SSLClientKeyRingPW="path of password file"
HTTPServer=<Http Server name>
HTTPServerPort=443
URIName=<URI name>
SSLClientCAKeyRing="same as SSLClientKeyRing"
SSLClientCAKeyRingPW="same as SSLClientKeyRingPW"
SSLClientCipherSuites=SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
SSLServer=true
SSLServerProtocols=TLSv1.2
SSLServerKeyRing="path of key ring PFX file"
SSLServerKeyRingPW="path of password file"
SSLServerCAKeyRing="same as SSLServerKeyRing"
SSLServerCAKeyRingPW="same as SSLServerCAKeyRing"
SSLServerCipherSuites=SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

What you are missing is that the route is configured from the standpoint of the TLS session, you are either:

1. TLS Server (you are receiving the inbound connection and decrypting it)
2. TLS Client (you are connecting out to another queue manager or MQIPT and encrypting)

To accept a TLS connection from your MQ client application you need to configure the `SSLServer*` equivalents to the already configured `SSLClient*` settings.

Comment: Just a small question after everything working fine, we are getting sockeTimeout  at mqipt after multiple successful connection.  we are getting MQRC_Connection broken issue. This is not very frequent , but after multiple sending or receiving messages we are getting this.

Comment: When the channel is running what is the HBINT reported in channel status?

Comment: It was discussed in the comments to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284625/ibm-mq-session-disconnects) how to perform a IBM MQ java trace as well as how to see the negotiated heartbeat interval.  Could you try this to find out what your HBINT is.  I am going to guess that your disconnects are after some period of inactivity?

Comment: currently we are pushing messages on every 3 second  in between that we are geeting this issue

Comment: On every 3 second we are creating connection and pushing messages and after that closing connection.

Comment: That is a terrible design.  The connection to a queue manager is the most expensive operation, and in this case you have thrown MQIPT in the middle which has to decrypte/encrypt each of those connections.  I would suggest your logic be changed to connect once and send message every 3 seconds and only disconnect when you shutdown the application.  On the actual issue, what do the MQIPT logs show at the time you get the connection broken?  Are you sure you are really closing the connection each 3 seconds?

Comment: Is it possible that the connection is not being closed and you are maxing out the threads on MQIPT?  I see you have it set to min 5 max 100 with IdleTimeout=20, this would mean that if the connection was not being closed by the app properly, that a new thread would be started for each inbound connection up to 100, if any of those threads reached 20 seconds of no activity they would be closed and you would receive a 2009 ont he client end.  With a normal well behaved application there should be no reason to have IdleTimeout set at all, and even if set that seems like a very low number.

Comment: I believe I have answered the question you have originally asked here, please accept my answer and if you appreciate it and haven't already please upvote it as well.  Please open a new question with more details on how the sending app logic is written, it is good to provide specifics on how you open the connection and close the connection.  Also background on why a message is sent every 3 second?

Comment: ok @JoshMac thanks alot . This input resolved my mqipt issues. now i will create a separate question for the same. Already upovted this answer :)