# IBM MQ session disconnects

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am creating an MQ listener like this and it works fine but then after minutes or hours disconnects with this exception.  I don't control the server.  This is over a dedicated circuit, not the internet. I doubt it's a network issue.  Other services run on the same circuit without issue.

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
QueueConnection qc;
Queue queue;
QueueSession queueSession;
QueueReceiver qr;

public void init() throws JMSException, IOException {
    cf.setQueueManager(" ");
    cf.setCCDTURL(Path.of(getCcdt()).toUri().toURL());
    cf.setSSLPeerName(getSslPeerName());
    qc = cf.createQueueConnection();
    qc.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onException(JMSException exception) {
            log.error(exception);
        }
    });
    queue = new MQQueue(cp.getMqQueue());
    queueSession = qc.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    qr = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
    qr.setMessageListener(this);
    qc.start();
}
```

exception:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:217) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:273) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.consumer(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:686) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.callConsumer(RemoteProxyQueue.java:3755) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.processEvent(RemoteProxyQueue.java:4824) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.driveConsumer(RemoteProxyQueue.java:4645) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.deliverMsgs(RemoteProxyQueue.java:5240) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.deliverMsgsReconnectable(RemoteDispatchThread.java:557) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.deliverMsgs(RemoteDispatchThread.java:531) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:305) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:319) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:99) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:343) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:312) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.0.0.jar:9.2.0.0 - p920-L200710.DE]
```

grep -C 0 -i -a etHeartbeatInterval mq.log

```
[2:30:37.720.09]  00000065  @16c85cc4  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]
--
[2:30:37.721.0X]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]
--
[2:30:37.795.1J]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [10(0xa)]
[2:30:37.795.1K]  00000065  @7b481be3  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  {  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean) [10(0xa)] [false]
[2:30:37.795.1L]  00000065  @7b481be3  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  }  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean)
--
[2:30:37.807.0N]  00000065  @43212202  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  {  getHeartbeatInterval(boolean) [true]
[2:30:37.807.0O]  00000065  @43212202  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  }  getHeartbeatInterval(boolean) returns [300(0x12c)] Integer
[2:30:37.807.0P]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [10(0xa)]
[2:30:37.807.0Q]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [300(0x12c)]
--
[2:30:37.811.01]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
--
[2:30:37.811.03]  00000065  @a5146c3   c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  {  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean) [300(0x12c)] [true]
--
[2:30:37.811.05]  00000065  @a5146c3   c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  }  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean)
--
[2:30:37.817.10]  00000067  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+-  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
--
[2:30:37.826.0F]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
[2:30:37.826.0G]  00000065  @38eff414  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  {  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean) [300(0x12c)] [true]
[2:30:37.826.0H]  00000065  @38eff414  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+----  }  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean)
--
[2:30:37.838.0X]  00000065  @71ff40ae  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+----  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
[2:30:37.838.0Y]  00000065  @1bb7bbb4  c.i.m.j.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection  ----+----+----+----+----  {  protocolSetHeartbeatInterval(int) [300(0x12c)]
[2:30:37.838.0Z]  00000065  @1bb7bbb4  c.i.m.j.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection  ----+----+----+----+----  }  protocolSetHeartbeatInterval(int)
--
[2:30:37.948.1A]  00000065  @22b76f8e  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]
--
[2:30:37.957.0C]  00000065  @716fc5e   c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]
--
[2:30:37.958.1T]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+--  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]
--
[2:30:38.039.0K]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [10(0xa)]
[2:30:38.039.0L]  00000065  @1cf5776d  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  {  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean) [10(0xa)] [false]
[2:30:38.039.0M]  00000065  @1cf5776d  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  }  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean)
--
[2:30:38.052.0O]  00000065  @3ed71710  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  {  getHeartbeatInterval(boolean) [true]
[2:30:38.052.0P]  00000065  @3ed71710  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  }  getHeartbeatInterval(boolean) returns [300(0x12c)] Integer
[2:30:38.052.0Q]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [10(0xa)]
[2:30:38.052.0R]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [300(0x12c)]
--
[2:30:38.056.02]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
[2:30:38.056.03]  00000065  @218f5897  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  {  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean) [300(0x12c)] [true]
[2:30:38.056.04]  00000065  @218f5897  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  }  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean)
--
[2:30:38.061.00]  00000069  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+-  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
--
[2:30:38.072.0I]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
[2:30:38.072.0J]  00000065  @5d299189  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  {  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean) [300(0x12c)] [true]
[2:30:38.072.0K]  00000065  @5d299189  c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID                 ----+----+----+----+---  }  setHeartbeatInterval(int,boolean)
--
[2:30:38.085.02]  00000065  @4c4e13bb  c.i.mq.exits.MQCD                        ----+----+----+----+---  d  getHeartbeatInterval() getter [300(0x12c)]
[2:30:38.085.03]  00000065  @51b68e6a  c.i.m.j.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection  ----+----+----+----+---  {  protocolSetHeartbeatInterval(int) [300(0x12c)]
--
[2:30:38.085.05]  00000065  @51b68e6a  c.i.m.j.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection  ----+----+----+----+---  }  protocolSetHeartbeatInterval(int)
```

Disconnects appear at either after 90 mins or else approx 50 mins:

```
15:28 start
16:59 restart (90 min)
17:55 restart (55 min)
18:51 restart (54 min)
19:47 restart (56 min)

3:06 start
4:47 restart (90 min)
5:38 restart (50 min)
6:34 restart (56 min
7:25 restart (50 min)
8:21 restart (55 min)
9:57 restart (95 min)
10:48 restart (50 min)
11:39 restart (51 min)
12:30 restart (51 min)
13:26 restart (56 min)
14:22 restart (56 min)
15:13 restart (51 min)
```

Packet capture looks like this.  See #162, I sent TLS packet, then 9 retrans, then disconnect 60 sec after #162 was sent.

```
192.168.77.102 = me (MQ JMS client)
192.168.77.1 = router(next hop)
160.43.166.189 = MQ server
```

[image: packet capture]

Comment: `MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN (2009)` indicates that either the network connection had a issue (aka was "broken") or that the client did not receive a heartbeat (HB) response from the queue manager in time.  You mention it is `over a dedicated circuit` which would indicate that it may pass through other special network devices such as firewalls or load balancers, any of these could add there own session level timeout.

Comment: With MQ the HB is sent by the client to the server after HBINT seconds of no other channel activity, if the QMGR does not receive a HB from the client in HBINT+5 it will send a HB to the client.  If the HBINT is less than 60 seconds, which ever side sent the HB will wait HBINT seconds for a response before throwing a 2009, if the HBINT is greater greater than or equal to 60 seconds then the which ever side sent the HB will wait 60 seconds for a response before throwing a 2009.  HBINT is negotiated at the start of the channel to the higher of the value of the queue manager and client.

Comment: With Java MQ clients that do not have a CCDT, they will always present the queue manager with HBINT(1) which in effect means that the HBINT will always negotiate to the Qmgr HBINT value.  By default MQ channels have a HBINT(300) which means that HBs are only sent ever 5 minutes when there is no other activity and they will wait 60 seconds for a response.  If you have a load balancer/firewall that has a timeout of less than 5 minutes then when your channel is not actively sending data it may go idle and be disconnected before a HB is sent.

Comment: @JoshMc, thanks for the helpful info!  I ran packet captures and found: My client sends a TLS packet to the MQ server.  200ms later I have received nothing back.  I being sending TCP Retransmission of the TLS data.  After 9 retrans in 60 sec I disconnect/reconnect and everything is fine again.  So I guess it's a network issue on the server, not MQ after all.   Or if it's MQ it's MQ on the server, not my client.

Comment: What is HBINT on the SVRCONN channel?

Comment: DIS CHL(*) ALL on the CCDT given to me by the service provider includes CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN), HBINT(10).   I presume to get the counterpart values from SVRCONN I need to ask them?

Comment: also my client CCDT has KAINT(AUTO)

Comment: You could take a IBM MQ Java trace and the values will show up there.   KAINT has no purpose on a CLNTCONN.

Comment: I set com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=on.  Wow, that's some copious logging.  I grepped for HBINT and it's not there.   It does show this, does that mean the server side is 1 sec but my client is 10 sec?:  c.i.m.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment(JmqiEnvironment)... newMQCD() returns [... heartbeatInterval:1(0x1)

Comment: If the remote side's config appears in my logs, it's hard to see them.  I do also see this which I maybe my client side?   c.i.mq.exits.MQCD ... setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]

Comment: Do you use the CCDT or do you pass the hostname/port/channel, etc in a different way?  You should see three line in a row `c.i.m.j.remote.rfp.RfpID ... getHeartbeatInterval(boolean) returns [10(0xa)] Integer`,  `c.i.mq.exits.MQCD ... getHeartbeatInterval() getter [10(0xa)]`, `c.i.mq.exits.MQCD ... setHeartbeatInterval(int) setter [10(0xa)]`.  1st line is SVRCONN value, 2nd is what you sent to Qmgr, 3rd is negotiated value (highest of the two).

Comment: Yours being 10 is a reasonable heart beat, and it is unlikely that a network device is timing your session out in less than 10 seconds. I have seen where the default of 300 seconds (5 minutes) can some times have problems with firewall time outs for example. You could check with the remote end to see what they see in there queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` at the time you see the disconnect, but I would agree it is likely not your problem based on your packet capture.

Comment: Everything is via the CCDT provided.  Grepped log output during reconnect is added to the question above.  It appears we start at 10 but eventually negotiate up to 300.  Do you agree?  Should I tell the remote side to decrease to 10?  Thanks!

Comment: I would agree.   When you have disconnects, it's it during periods of idle time when there is no message traffic?

Comment: Seems unrelated to message traffic.  We have no msg traffic today (sunday) and the reset times are added above.  It appear the first disconnect happens after 90 mins and subsequent disconnects are about 50 mins apart.  Disconnects happen under msg load during the week also.

Comment: What is the OS tcp keepalive set to on your server?

Comment: CentOS 8 defaults on my machine.  No idea about the service provider's end.
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75

Comment: Are you able to tell based on the packet capture what value is negotiated, I think the smaller of the two is what will be chosen.

Comment: Do you mean value negotiated by the MQ proto between the 7200 sec TCP value and the 300 sec MQ value?  I can't see in the MQ packets because we're using TLS and I haven't put those keys in wireshark yet. I assume that would be in the TLS payload.  I could understand having some issue at the 5 min or 2 hour mark, but why 90 mins, then 55 minutes thereafter?   I added the packet capture screenshot above around the disconnect time.

Comment: Keepalive is negotiated at the TCP layer and separate from MQ level HBINT.

Comment: Then I believe it's the 7200 sec value because a few min after a reconnect "ss -te" shows  "timer:(keepalive,115min,0) uid:1000 ino:107270662 sk:320 <->".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222884/discussion-between-joshmc-and-andrew).

Answer (score 0):

The service provider had to set HBINT(30) on their end to fix the issue.  Very odd that they wouldn't have had that correct already considering they set up loads of these sessions.

Comment: Hi Andrew, given that this did end up being the fix, I would like to detail most of the troubleshooting info and suggestions I provided in the comments in an answer, would you be willing to accept that as an answer?

Comment: @JoshMc Sorry for the late reply.  Yes, of course.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: You mentioned no firewall, is it possible a firewall is on the remote side?

Comment: The firewall wasn't an issue.  The service provider (Bloomberg) was using a HBINT that wasn't compatible with what they published in their CCDT file.  Everything worked after they fixed it.

Comment: Hi Andrew.  The HBINT is negotiated at startup to the highest value, so there really is not a concept of the SVRCONN HBINT being incompatible with the HBINT that was in the CCDT file.  In your case this just means the HBINT negotiated to 300 seconds.

Comment: I mentioned before that my suggestion to have the lower it was to HBINT set on the SVRCONN was to have the channels HB each other more frequently to prevent network devices (such as Firewalls or Loadbalancers) from timing our session out.  It also has the added benefit that the client and server will notice a broken connection much sooner.  Given that this did resolve your problem I still think some type of network device between your client server and the service provider's MQ server was timing the connection out periodically.

Comment: It could be explained why you saw various timeouts between 50 and 90 minutes if the network timeout was also 300 seconds, it then becomes a race condition on if your HB is going to be sent to keep the session alive before the 300 second timeout closes the session.  Glad to hear that it did get resolved.